# How to submit different parts of a form independently?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

As depicted by the image, how am I able to a tag via 'Add Tag' independently of the rest of the form, that is in a sense to ignore the validation of the rest of the form. Also, vice versa, how can I 'Create' a recipe while ignoring the validation of adding a tag 'Add Tag'

Note: The red lines are just for css debugging.

[image: Image of the View]

**The view:**

```
@model MVCApp.ViewModels.CreateRecipe

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Recipe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create Recipe</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @*Heading - Select Multiple Tags:*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedTagIds, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", style = "border: 1px solid red;" })
        </div>

        @*Search box - Tag*@
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" style="margin: 10px;width: 165px;border: 1px solid red;" onkeyup="filter()">

        @*List Box - Tag*@
        <div class="form-group" style="border: 1px solid black;">

            @*List box*@
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4" id="listBoxDiv" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTagIds, Model.TagList, new { @class = "col-xs-12", style = "height:300px; padding:5px;", @onchange = "getSelectedTags(this)" }) @*//OnSelectedIndexChanged*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedTagIds, "", new { @class = "text-danger col-xs-12", style = "border: 1px solid red;" })
            </div>

            @*Your tags selected*@
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8" style="border: 1px solid red;" id="displaySelectedTags">
            </div>
        </div>

        @*EditorFor & Submit - Tag Name*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "border: 1px solid red;" }) @*sm*@
            <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 1px solid red; padding-right:0;">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            @*Submit - Add Tag*@
            <div class="col-md-7" id="addTag" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" class="btn btn-default" style="border: 1px solid red;" />
            </div>
        </div>

        @*File - Upload Image*@
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="file">Upload Image:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width:100%" />
            </div>
        </div>

        @*EditorFor - Recipe Title*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recipe.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recipe.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recipe.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*EditorFor - Recipe Instructions*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Recipe.Instructions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*Submit - Create Recipe*@
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**The controller Post method:** (work in progress)

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateRecipe model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // Insert Image
                    if (file != null)
                    {

                    }

                    // Insert Recipe
                    int recipeId = RecipeProcessor.CreateRecipe(model.Recipe.Name, model.Recipe.Instructions);

                    // Insert TagRecipe Row
                    var count = 0;
                    foreach (var tagId in model.SelectedTagIds)
                    {
                        RecipeProcessor.CreateTagRecipe(tagId, recipeId);
                        count++;
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { successMessage = $"{model.Recipe.Name} added successfully" });
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }

            // If not valid, return the same model - This should never run as JS will validate first
            return View(model);
        }
```

**The Model**

```
    public class CreateRecipe
    {
        // A Recipe object
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "At least one Tag is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Select multiple tags:")]
        public int[] SelectedTagIds { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TagList { get; set; }

        // A tag object
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are too many ways to do what you're asking for. **Read about Single-page applications (SPA)** and how to build SPAs with ASP .NET

Comment: You are not limited to one form per page. Just add another form with a different action.

Comment: @DonO This was my initial guess, but the 'Add Tag' portion/form would be inside the 'Create' recipe form?

Comment: No it would be outside i will try to put a brief answer with a sample below.

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete Given that a SPA is just dynamically rewriting the current web page, instead of the default method of the browser loading entire new pages, I still wouldn't know where to specifically start researching to be able to submit only part of a form while ignoring the validation of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple forms on the same page, pointing to different actions. If you need access to two models than your view model for the page should contain both models inside like you have them already.

Controller will have two actions one for adding recipe and one for adding tag or it can point to two different controllers.

The view can have two forms also. In the below example they hit different controllers but you could also hit different actions on the same controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Recipe", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
.....
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Tag", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
.....
}
```

One thing to keep in mind if you do it this way is that both actions might be called at the same time, so you would need a way in code to determine which one are you doing.

Comment: On the View as I have it now, the "Add Tag" portion is in-between the "Create" recipe. (The ListBox is for the "Create" recipe).

I don't see how I can one form on top of another as you have shown, yet have the "Add Tag" portion wedged in-between the Create recipe form like it is displayed on the view currently.

Comment: I can only see it working if visually portions/inputs from one form are stacked on top of another form and there is no mixing visually.